# Ordering by Nullness of field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by

Hello all :) I'm strugglind to come up with the right SQL syntax in Oracle 10g. I would like to come up with something like this:

```
SELECT
  LAST_VALUE FIELD_INFO OVER(ORDER BY FIELD_1 IS NULL, FIELD_2, FIELD_1)
FROM TABLE_1
```

`FIELD_1 IS NULL` raising a syntax error.

How would you do it?

Comment: Are Nulls to come before or after nonNulls?

Comment: @DavidAldridge In MySQL syntax (which seems to be what he's aiming for), it would put NULLs last. I guess it may just be an example though.

Comment: do you meant something like `ORDER BY FIELD_1 NULLS LAST, FIELD_2, FIELD_1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NULLs First**

This expression is a compact Oracle syntax to return 0 for Nulls and 1 for non-Nulls

```
Order by NVL2(FIELD_1,1,0), ...
```

Or you could use a case statement:

```
Order by Case when FIELD_1 is null then 0 else 1 end, ...
```

**NULLs Last**

```
Order by NVL2(FIELD_1,0,1)

Order by Case when FIELD_1 is null then 1 else 0 end, ...
```

There's *possibly* a fractional optimisation in this method:

```
Order by Case when FIELD_1 is null then null else 0 end nulls last, ...
```

... through requiring slightly less sort area.

Comment: NVL2 is a nice solution, I think you got your values swapped though.

Comment: Why the `CASE`? Shouldn't a simple `NULLS LAST/FIRST` be sufficient?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well the requirement is to sort by the nullness of col1 alone, then the value of col2, then the value of co1.

Comment: `nulls last/first` is specified for each column (similar to `asc` or `desc`): `order by col1 nulls last, col2, col3`

Comment: The point of that last code fragment was to demonstrate that you do not need to change the values to 0 and 1 to order them -- you can change then to null and anything-that-is-not-null and use the extra clause to provide an explicit order

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a compound field and sort by it

```
COALESCE(FIELD_1,'[lots of spaces to ensure they go first]')||FIELD_2
```

But it would really help if you post 10-20 example records to show exactly, what you want to achieve.